# Convert datetime in decimal trough angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angular-ui-grid

I would like to ask you, how can I convert decimal number to data in angularJS?

source:
20150911141804
expected:
2015-09-11

I need format this source number inside cellTemplate in ui-grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display something you're getting from a data source, like a `JSON` file or a `$http.get(...)`, then using a filter is the way to go, but I suggest you build a custom one, seeing your format is quite uncommon.

If you need to parse a value entered by a user in, say, an input text, then the right way is to use a custom parser.

If you want to know more you can read the official docs for [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) and [parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span><br>
```

refer to 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

Your date has a very strange format.
If you cannot change it (to an UNIX timestamp for example), consider converting your date (as a String) to something like:

```
20150911141804 => '2015-09-11'
```

And then create a new date from this String :

```
var date = new Date('2015-09-11');
```

Once you have a real Date object, you can format it using angular's native date filter or momentjs.